# Endless generating dSYM in Fastlane

Tags: ios, macos, circleci, fastlane

I develop iOS application and I use fastlane to distribute ad-hoc *.ipa.

then I'd like to use integrate with CircleCI pipeline but I stuck in this step too long times until it terminated by timeout.

```
[06:45:29]: ▸ Running script 'Run Script - Crashlytics'
[06:45:29]: ▸ Generating 'LordGift\ App.app.dSYM' 

......( fastlane summary )........

[06:55:30]: fastlane finished with errors

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

Here is my CircleCI pipeline

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    macos:
      xcode: 13.3.1 

    steps:
      - checkout
      - ....
      - run:
          name: Deploy via Fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane deploy_sit


workflows:
  build_to_sit:
    jobs:
      - build_and_deploy
```

UPDATED !!!

After disable xcpretty, it stuck in this line.

```
INFO [2022-04-27 07:04:05.09]: ▸ /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign .....
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15518 ?